# Como obtener los productos de un mismo tipo con limit y offset? sql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla de productos terminados, y cada vez que se termina un producto esta es ingresado a esta tabla, el id es auto incrementable, por lo que a la hora de seleccionar los productos por su tipo estos devolveran sus propios id, mi pregunta es si yo quiero seleccionar todos los productos de tipo syrup, tengo que devolver todos los products de tipo syrup, pero de 5 en 5, como hago para devolverlos de manera ordenada? estoy usando order by id que funciona la primera vez ya que te seleccionara el menor id de ese tipo que seria el primero y limit 5 hasta el 5 mayor, como selecciono desde el 6 mayor hasta el 10mo mayor y asi sucesivamente?

dejo la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

supongamos que quiero seleccionar de 5 en 5 los productos que se llamen weisen u 100, la consulta seria:

```
SELECT * FROM `finished_products` WHERE name = "weisen u 100" ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

este me devuelve desde el id 7 hasta el id 13, ahora la segunda consulta como seria para que me devuelva desde el 14 hasta el 17? tengo pensando en guardar el ultimo id en una variable, en tal caso seria 13, y este insertarla en la consuta, quedando:

```
SELECT * FROM `finished_products` WHERE name = "weisen u 100" ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 5 OFFSET 13
```

pero no funciona, gracias si pudiera darme una mano :)

Comment: `OFFSET` no funciona asi, el campo `id` es irrelevante, en lugar de 13 deberia ser 5, ya que te va a devolver los siguientes 5 registros sin importar que id tengan.

Comment: pero sin el campo id, este me devuelve directamente desde el 14 hasta el 17, sin pasar antes por los menores

Comment: Me refiero a la segunda consulta, si quieres hacerlo dinamico necesitas una forma de guardar el numero de pagina.

Comment: ya vi, el offset se evaluaria desde el comienzo de la fila hasta las siguentes 5, es decir offset 3, desde la fila 3 hasta las siguentes 5 ordenando las id, pero hay alguna manera de obtener fila del ultimo registro en sql?

Comment: Necesitas guardar la pagina en una variable y tu consulta quedaria asi: `SELECT * FROM finished_products WHERE name = "weisen u 100" ORDER BY id LIMIT 5 OFFSET pagina * 5`

Comment: la pagina en tal caso seria la ultima fila de los primeros 5 resultados, con esa fila guardada, puedo usarla el offset para que esta busque desde ahi, pero no encuentro ninguna manera de que me devuelva esa fila en la que se seleccionaron los 5 primero, solo esta count, pero este me selecciona todos de una

Comment: Incorrecto, la pagina que te devuelve los primeros 5 resultados seria la pagina 0, la siguiente pagina, que empieza con el id 13 seria la pagina 1 y asi sucesivamente.

Comment: ya lo resolvi amigo, offset al comienzo tiene que ser 0, ya despues la segunda consulta se iguala a limit porque ya esas filas fueron retornadas, por lo que comenzaria desde el ulitmo limit, y para la tercera el offset seria el triple de limit y asi sucesivamente

Comment: quedaria asi:

SELECT * FROM finished_products where name = "weisen u 100" ORDER BY id LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0 (esta consulta recorrera desde el comienzo de la tabla buscando 5 resultados ordenado por id con el nombre weisen u 100), la segunda seria SELECT * FROM finished_products where name = "weisen u 100" ORDER BY id LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5, offset es 5 ya que eso le indicaria que comienze desde la 5 fila (es decir los 5 devueltos anteriormente) a buscar 5 mas y asi, seria luego 10, 15, 20